# MySql Query - Reverse Query

Tags: mysql, reverse

I need to Create a View.

The complication comes from the way the Table Data is captured and the way I need to construct the query.

Table: Games

```
id  |  GameID  |  ParentGameID  |  Name
1   |  5       |  0             |  Soccer
2   |  6       |  5             |  England
3   |  7       |  6             |  Premier League
4   |  8       |  7             |  Man U vs Liverpool
```

I need to construct a Tournament Name

eg: England - Premier League - Man U vs Liverpool

Note I ignored the Soccer Name as this is the sport. I only want to construct the Tournament Name.

Not sure if this is possible, but any help will be greatly appreciated.

Note that the ParentGame ID is the key that determines the next part of the Tname.

ie.: Man U vs Liv has a ParentGameID of 7, which is the GameID of the Premier League, which has a ParentGameID of 6 which is the GameID of England and so forth.

Comment: Is it always exactly 3 levels?

Comment: This site may be helpful: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: how you want wished result to be ?

Comment: Hi there, Barmar, no they wont be restricted to 3 levels, some may have 2 other may have more.

Comment: Echo_Me6, I want the result to be as per the example I gave:

Comment: eg. England - Premier League - Man U vs Liverpool

Comment: Out-of-the-box, MySQL does not support recursion so options include 1. write a sproc, 2. join the table to itself as often as could possibly be required, 3. handle the logic at the application level (e.g. bit of PHP), 4. switch to another model (e.g. nested set)

Comment: I've actually made some headway using the link that Barmar posted on Hierarchical Data.